# pandas big dataframe to_pickle causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pickle

I have big dataframe, and I see to_pickle would lead to segmentation fault while to_csv would do fine, what could be the reason, please?

I am using python-3.6.4.

Comment: How big is the resulting csv?

Comment: About 70G uncompressed.

Comment: I've had the same issue, and found that I can't really pickle any files >= 15 GB or so, so I've resorted to splitting them up. I tried switching to HDF5, but that seems to be plagued by this issue: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/531, which may or may not be related.

Comment: My big dataframe is a result of concatenating many smaller ones. It's very odd that after dumping the big df into csv, and then read it back with `pd.read_csv`, then `to_pickle` works. I am being very curious why.

Comment: same issue with `to_pickle` on large data...